# Any good resources on design patterns for parallel architectures?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, parallel-processing, gpgpu

A bit of background:

I am getting started with GPGPU (OpenCL), I am using a java wrapper ([jogamp.jocl](http://jogamp.org/jocl/www/)) hoping that it will provide me with a way to abstract the low level nitty gritty and use standard OOP at higher levels. I can see already from the various Hello World examples that I'll have to manage the queues myself.

My question:

**Are there any known patterns for GPGPU or good resources (as in books) on design patterns for massively parallel architectures in general?**

My focus is on biological simulations, but really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Johnldol please let me know how jogamp.jocl proves itself - I'm really interested in finding a good wrapper.

Comment: @Dave well my very little experience so far has been quite positive with jogamp.jocl - it was easy enough to setup on mac environment ('cause its already OpenCL enabled). Having a bit of trouble on windows, but the problem is the AATI drivers there. I also tried jocl.org (not the same as jogamp.jocl) but ran into a number of issues.

Comment: @Dave also the jogamp.jocl community seems quite active and I got good answers from @mbien on the forums when I ran into issues --> http://jogamp.org/forum.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say that similar patterns apply as for distributed computing for higher level abstractions. Not necessary the concurrency patters but all which help splitting tasks for parallel and independent execution. For example map/reduce. A CLCommandQueue would be used like a worker thread. Its basically just an interface to a abstract device (piece of hardware).

Comment: thanks for pitching in! would you have any example to point out that might help me wrap my head around this, or even resources in terms of distributed computing patterns? My background is mainly enterprise development so parallelism is only used when you run out of options :)

Comment: I have widened the scope of original question

Answer (score 1):

[Architectural Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.sigsoft.org/phdDissertations/theses/JorgeOrtega.pdf)

[Ralph Johnson on Parallel Programming Patterns](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/Ralph-Johnson-Parallel-Programming-Patterns)

Comment: thanks for helping. Found the 1st link on google, but wasn't exactly useful. The 2nd one is very interesting though. they talk about 'the upcoming book'. this was 2009, did it come out in the end? Can't seem to find it.